# scrollview not working from database images

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, nsmutablearray

I stored some images in local database. I fetched images from database using sqlite and displayed using array. Then i added that image array in to scrollview. But scrollview is not working.

code:

.h file:

```
NSMutableArray *arraysofs;
-(void)unloadPreviousPage:(int)index;
-(void)loadNextPage:(int)index;
```

.m file:

```
 -(void)click:(id)sender{


        scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;



        for (int i = 0; i<[self.arraysofs count]; i++ ) {
            NSLog(@"index %d",i);



            mmageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+(i*74), 420, 72, 72)];

           [mmageView setImage:((Mysof *) [self.arraysofs objectAtIndex:i]).photo];

           [scroll addSubview:mmageView];

          }


        [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetMaxX(mmageView.frame),self.view.frame.size.height)];

       [self.view addSubview:scroll];


    }
```

Comment: what is the size of `self.arraysofs`???

Comment: that's mmageView take size of self.arraysofs. self.arraysofs images are displaying. But i can't scroll

Comment: how many images you have???

Comment: UIScrillView Scrolls only when its content size is greater than its frame 4x74 = 288.. So i think it might be a problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your Click methos set the content size of your scrollview like as follows,

```
-(void)click:(id)sender{

for (int index = 0; index < [self.arraysofs count]; index ++ ) {
         NSLog(@"index %d",index);

        mmageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+(index*74), 52, 72, 72)];

        [self.view addSubview:mmageView];

        Soflistsql * mysofs =[[Soflistsql alloc] init];
        self.arraysofs = [mysofs getMyLists];
        [mmageView setImage:((Mysof *) [self.arraysofs objectAtIndex:index]).photo];
    }

[your_ScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetMaxX(mmageView.frame),self.view.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Comment: I tried this method. It's not working. I need to make horizontal scrollview

Comment: that is what i did in `[your_ScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetMaxX(mmageView.frame),self.view.frame.size.height)];` ... Apart from that what is the problem for you??